# Android Room Insert To Join Table Doesn't Work

Tags: android, database, sqlite, kotlin

I've been looking around and couldn't find any explanation why this was happening.
I've tried opening my db file in apps like sqliteman and running "INSERT INTO" queries myself and it works just fine that way. Yet, whatever Room does doesn't seem to be working, it doesn't crash or anything, it just doesn't insert anything.

So basically I have 2 tables connected in a m-n relation via a join table:

1) Song table

```
@Entity(tableName = RoomDbConstants.TABLE_NAME_SONGS,
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(entity = Album::class,
            parentColumns = [RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_ALBUM_ARTIST_NAME, RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_ALBUM_NAME],
            childColumns = [RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_SONG_ARTIST_NAME, RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_SONG_ALBUM_NAME],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE),
        ForeignKey(entity = Genre::class,
                parentColumns = [RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_GENRE_NAME],
                childColumns = [RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_SONG_GENRE_NAME],
                onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)])
data class Song(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_SONG_ID)
    val id: Long?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_SONG_DATA)
    val songData: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_SONG_NAME)
    val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_SONG_ALBUM_NAME)
    val albumName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_SONG_ARTIST_NAME)
    val artistName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_SONG_GENRE_NAME)
    val genreName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_SONG_TRACK_NUMBER)
    val trackNumber: Int = RoomDbConstants.TRACK_NUMBER_DEFAULT,
    @ColumnInfo(name = RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_SONG_YEAR_PUBLISHED)
    val yearPublished: Int = RoomDbConstants.YEAR_PUBLISHED_NONE,
    @ColumnInfo(name = RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_SONG_START_TIME_IN_MILLIS)
    val startTimeInMillis: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_SONG_END_TIME_IN_MILLIS)
    val endTimeInMillis: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_SONG_DURATION_IN_MILLIS)
    val durationInMillis: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_SONG_COVER_DATA)
    val coverData: String?)
```

2) Playlist table

```
@Entity(tableName = RoomDbConstants.TABLE_NAME_PLAYLISTS,
    indices = [Index(value = [RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_PLAYLIST_NAME], unique = true)])
data class Playlist(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_PLAYLIST_ID)
    val id: Long?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_PLAYLIST_NAME)
    val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_PLAYLIST_COVER_DATA)
    val coverData: String?)
```

3) SongsPlaylistsLink (The table that connects between Songs and Playlists)

```
@Entity(tableName = RoomDbConstants.TABLE_NAME_SONGS_PLAYLISTS_LINKS,
    primaryKeys = [RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_SONGS_PLAYLISTS_LINK_SONG_ID,
        RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_SONGS_PLAYLISTS_LINK_PLAYLIST_ID],
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(entity = Song::class,
            parentColumns = [RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_SONG_ID],
            childColumns = [RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_SONGS_PLAYLISTS_LINK_SONG_ID],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE),
        ForeignKey(entity = Playlist::class,
                parentColumns = [RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_PLAYLIST_ID],
                childColumns = [RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_SONGS_PLAYLISTS_LINK_PLAYLIST_ID],
                onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)],
    indices = [Index(value = [RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_SONGS_PLAYLISTS_LINK_SONG_ID,
    RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_SONGS_PLAYLISTS_LINK_PLAYLIST_ID], unique = true)])
data class SongsPlaylistsLink(
    @ColumnInfo(name = RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_SONGS_PLAYLISTS_LINK_SONG_ID)
    val songId: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = RoomDbConstants.COLUMN_SONGS_PLAYLISTS_LINK_PLAYLIST_ID)
    val playlistId: Long)
```

Insert function:

```
@Insert
fun insert(songsPlaylistsLink: SongsPlaylistsLink)
```

So here's what I tried to do:
I already have songs and playlists in the database.
So let's say I have a song with an ID of 1 and a playlist with an ID of 1.
When I do insert(SongsPlaylistsLink(1,1)) nothing happens.
The table is still empty.

Any help on why this happens will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at the actual code that was generated by Room for your DAO?

Comment: Yes and I haven't found anything wrong with it. Here's the query for the insert function: "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO `SONGS_PLAYLISTS_LINKS`(`SONGS_PLAYLISTS_LINK_SONG_ID`,`SONGS_PLAYLISTS_LINK_PLAYLIST_ID`) VALUES (?,?)"

Comment: So, if there is an SQL error, it will get ignored. Try using `OnConflictStrategy.FAIL` and see if the error will get propagated. Also, you can try and debug to see what happens during the execution of this call.

Comment: I tried using FAIL and still nothing. I tried debugging but as I said, the code executes but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like running db.beginTransaction() and db.endTransaction() before and after the insert statements respectively doesn't work all that well. Removing it fixed it for me.

Comment: Did you call `setTransactionSuccessful()` before calling `endTransaction()`? If you didn't to it, then your transaction will be rolled back and all changes are going to be reverted. There is convenience method `RoomDatabase.runInTransaction(Runnable)` that can be used to run something as a transaction. You can check it's source code to see how to correctly use transactions in Room.